# Is it possible to count the number of items in a xslt key?

Tags: xslt, key

I have this key, which may be empty:

```
<xsl:key 
         name="k1" 
         match="div[contains(@class, 'contents')]/node()[not(self::br) and not(ancestor-or-self::p)]" 
         use="generate-id(following-sibling::br[1])"/>
```

Currently to check if its empty (in a xsl:template block matching div[contains(@class, 'contents')]) I rerun the xpath (for example):

```
 <xsl:when test="count(node()[not(self::br) and not(ancestor-or-self::p)]) > 1">
```

Is there any why I can just count items in a key for example something like:

```
 <xsl:when test="count(key('k1', *) > 1">
```

I thought about using a `<xsl:for-each>` and assigning a isempty var to false, but hoping there is a cleaner way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the number of nodes mapped to a *particular* key value but not the total number of nodes known to the whole key (other than as the union of all the node sets mapped to each value).  I would define a second key with the same `match` but a different `use`:

```
<xsl:key 
     name="k2" 
     match="div[contains(@class, 'contents')]/node()[not(self::br) and not(ancestor-or-self::p)]" 
     use="generate-id(..)"/>
```

and then get the count within the `div[contains(@class, 'contents')]` template using `count(key('k2', generate-id()))`

Answer (score 1):

If you create a *second* key using a *constant* in the use attribute:

```
<xsl:key 
     name="k1_all" 
     match="div[contains(@class, 'contents')]/node()[not(self::br) and not(ancestor-or-self::p)]" 
     use="'all'"/>
```

you can then simply use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(key('k1_all','all'))"/>
```

At least like this you can place the two keys (one for lookup and one for counting) directly next to each other in the XSLT file, so that the complex XPaths are easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

**Simply use**:

```
count(//div[contains(@class, 'contents')]/node()
                              [not(self::br) and not(ancestor-or-self::p)])
```

Comment: thanks for the reply - that's effectively what I am doing, but was hoping that I didn't have to run the query multiple times, once to count and once to create he key.